# ASP.NET MVC 5 - How to get value Session into table data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, backend

I'm trying to get a value session and add it into a table

here is my code i tried to get value :

```
 public ActionResult CheckOut(FormCollection form)
        {
            try
            {
                Cart cart = Session["Cart"] as Cart;
                OrderPro _order = new OrderPro();//Bảng hóa đơn sản phẩm
                _order.DateOrder = DateTime.Now;
                _order.AddressDeliverry = form["AddressDelivery"];
                _order.IDCus = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
                db.OrderProes.Add(_order);
                foreach (var item in cart.Items)
                {
                    OrderDetail _order_detail = new OrderDetail();
                    _order_detail.IDOrder = _order.ID;
                    _order_detail.IDProduct = item.product.ProductID;
                    _order_detail.UnitPrice = (double)item.product.Price;
                    _order_detail.Quantity = item.quantity;
                    db.OrderDetails.Add(_order_detail);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                cart.ClearCart();
                return RedirectToAction("CheckOut_Success", "GioHang");
            }
            catch
            {

               return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Đã xảy ra lỗi, vui lòng kiểm tra thông tin');</script>");

            }
        }
```

here is the code Session :

```
public ActionResult Login(CustomerUser cus)
        {
            var check = db.CustomerUsers.Where(s => s.NameUser == cus.NameUser && s.PasswordUser == cus.PasswordUser).FirstOrDefault();
            if(check == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorLogin = "Sai info đăng nhập";
                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                Session["NameUser"] = cus.NameUser;
                Session["PasswordUser"] = cus.PasswordUser;
                Session["ID"] = cus.ID;
                return RedirectToAction("DichVu", "Product");
            }
        }
```

Here is the model Session ID :

```
public partial class CustomerUser
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CustomerUser()
        {
            this.OrderProes = new HashSet<OrderPro>();
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string NameUser { get; set; }
        public string PasswordUser { get; set; }
        public string PhoneUser { get; set; }
        public string EmailUser { get; set; }
    }
```

i tried to debug but i get a error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pewi8.png)

Comment: You're inserting a duplicate value at `CustomerUser` table. Check the value of `_order.ID` when adding the `_order_detail`.

Comment: when I delete _order.IDCus = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]); it is still working normally, do the foreign key and primary key is the cause of the error??